# Delphi 7 - ShowMessage to Stay on Top and not to be Able to Click Other Windows of applications unless you Press ''ok'' button in the message

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can i do that?

```
procedure TFMain.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ShowMessage('Cya!!');
Application.Terminate;
end;
```

Is there any way to be able to only click the ''OK'' from the ShowMessage and if I dont i wont be able to click anything else in my interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `MB_SYSTEMMODAL` flag on [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Instead of `ShowMessage`, call `MessageBox`directly, like this:

```
MessageBox(Application.Handle,'Cya!!',PChar(Application.Title),MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
```

Comment: I do feel that you need to explain what MB_SYSTEMMODAL does since its name dates from olden times when it really did lead to a system modal dialog.

Answer (score 3):

There is no supported way to show a window that prevents interaction with other applications.

You can use `ShowMessage` to show a modal dialog that will always appear top-most in your application, and whose modality covers all other windows in your application. That is the user is prevented from interacting with other windows in your application while the message box is shown. That is the maximum amount of modality that is supported by the system.

You can create a modal dialog that has the show on top property. You cannot prevent the user from interacting with other applications but you can make sure that your window is always on top of the window the user wants to work with. Take a minute now to consider how the user will react to your application doing that.

Should you decide that you want to do that you can use `MessageBox` with `MB_SYSTEMMODAL`. Or you can create your own form (or use `CreateMessageDialog`) and set its show on top property (set `FormStyle` to `fsStayOnTop`) before you call `ShowModal`.